Existence of transcendental complex numbers over some extension fields
Possibly a dumb question… We know, since Hermite’s result (1783), that there is a field $F$ over which $e$ is transcendental. $F=\mathbb{Q}$ is such a field and therefore, $e$ is also transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}(i)=\{a+bi, \: \vert \: a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.
But are there transcendental complex numbers $z$ over the extension field $F(e)$ (i.e such that $\{1, z, z^2, …, z^m, …\}$ are $F(e)$-linearly independent) ?
And is it the right definition of transcendental complex numbers over such a field ?
Many thanks for any help.

There are, because $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ is a countable field, and if the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}(e)$ was algebraic then $\mathbb{C}$ would be countable as well. But as we know, it isn't.

Thank you.  And if we consider a field $F$ that contains $i$ over which $e$ is transcendental. Is there any transcendental complex number over $F(e)$ ?

The same argument will work over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ as well. And over any countable field in general.

I see. Thank you.
